# How to refactor deeply nested functions?

Tags: if-statement, nested, refactoring, statements

My code currently looks like this:

```
If (case = 1)
{
    If (option = 1)
    {
        If (otherOption = 1)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 2)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 3)
            ;do something
    }
    else
    {
        If (otherOption = 1)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 2)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 3)
            ;do something
    }
}

else if (case = 2)
{
    If (option = 1)
    {
        If (otherOption = 1)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 2)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 3)
            ;do something
    }
    else
    {
        If (otherOption = 1)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 2)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 3)
            ;do something
    }
}

else if (case = 3)
{
    If (option = 1)
    {
        If (otherOption = 1)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 2)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 3)
            ;do something
    }
    else
    {
        If (otherOption = 1)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 2)
            ;do something
        else if (otherOption = 3)
            ;do something
    }
}
```

Obviously terrible and difficult to maintain. I want to add yet another super If statement on top of this, which splits this tree 6 times. Each ;do something does one line of code.

Any help on how to refactor this monstrosity? I've written a lot of code that looks like this and I dread working with it every time. I need a new way to approach these problems. Extending the functionality of this code requires a lot of work.

Comment: What is the programming paradigm to consider? Stuctural or OO?

Comment: Object-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you didn't specify the context of your application, it seems a scenario that could take advantage from the application of [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

The code you posted can be settled to act as the **Context** object with the responsibility of control the higher level condition of your outer if-else statement.
Within every block of if-else statement, a particular behaviour can be loaded using a  a **ConcreteStrategy** object (that usually implements a **Strategy** interface).

This pattern can be repeated for inner if-else blocks.

#### Example

Consider a game in which a **Character** moves around a 2D-map. Depending of its life indicator (e.g 0-200), it can moves of 2,5,8 tiles if he is,respectively,in a tired, ok or a super state.

The **Character** object acts like the "**Context** of the Strategy Pattern and he has the responsability of which **MoveStrategy** is correct for the situation.
Putting of life the correct **MoveStrategy** object and calling by forwarding the method **move()** throght the **move()** method of Character.

A hint for a Java implementation of the example:

```
public class Character{

    private int life=100;
    private int x=0 
    private int y=0; 
    private MoveStrategy strategy=new DefaultStrategy();


    public int getLife(){
        return life;
        }

        public void setLife(int value){
        this.life=value;
        }

    public void move(){
        if(life<30)
            strategy=new TiredStrategy();
        else if(life > 100)
            strategy=new SuperStrategy();
        else
            strategy=new DefaultStrategy();


        strategy.move();

    }
}



public interface MoveStrategy{

    public abstract void move();

}

public DefaultStrategy implements MoveStrategy{

    public void move(){
        System.out.println("Move character of 5 tiles");
    }
}

public TiredStrategy implements MoveStrategy{

    public void move(){
        System.out.println("Move character of 2 tiles");
    }
}

public SuperStrategy implements MoveStrategy{

    public void move(){
        System.out.println("Move character of 8 tiles");
    }
}
```

Comment: Incredibly helpful answer. This is much better and makes it easier to extend functionality. And easier to understand. Thank you so much.